# Zip collections matching by ID

Tags: c#, json, linq

This is a repost of a previous question that was wrongly closed as a duplicate:

Say I have two collections of the same type similar to the following:

OldCollection: [{ID: **1**, other props}, {ID: **2**, other props}, {ID: **3**, other props}]

NewCollection: [{ID: **1**, other props}, {ID: **3**, other props}, {ID: **4**, other props}]

Is there a way to zip the collections matching ID's to get a Tuple result like the following:

```
[{OLD-ID1, NEW-ID1},
 {OLD-ID2, null},
 {OLD-ID3, NEW-ID3},
 {null, NEW-ID4}]
```

So basically I want to zip the collections together matching on ID and if only one collection has an entry with a particular ID the Tuple should fill in null for that spot.

**IMPORTANT:** This is not a duplicate of the full outer join solution. I do not want to combine my results so that Col1-ID1 gets merged with Col2-ID1. I Just want to Tuple them so I can see them side by side. Think of it as Collection 1 is the old values and Collection 2 is the new values. I want them to be paired up into Tuples so I can see ID1 and ID3 were updated, ID2 was removed, and ID4 was added.

Here is a [DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3imDZV) that almost does what I want.
The results of that fiddle is:

```
 [
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "firstOld"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "firstNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "secondOld"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "thirdNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "thirdOld"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "fourthNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": null,
    "Item2": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "fifthNew"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want is this:

```
[
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "firstOld"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "firstNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "secondOld"
    },
    "Item2": null
  },
  {
    "Item1": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "thirdOld"
    },
    "Item2": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "thirdNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": null,
    "Item2": {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "fourthNew"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item1": null,
    "Item2": {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "fifthNew"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate? You want a full-outer join and assign `null` if one of both sides is not available.

Comment: It is not a join though. I don't want to merge Collection1.ItemId1 with Collection2.ItemId1 I want to keep them separate and just have them Tupled so I can see them individually side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a full-outer-join anyway, but you could use this easy approach:

```
var oldByID = oldCollection.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
var newByID = newCollection.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
IEnumerable<int> allIds = oldByID.Keys.Union(newByID.Keys);

var oldAndNew = allIds.Select(id =>
    (Old: oldByID.TryGetValue(id, out var oldObj) ? oldObj : null, 
     New: newByID.TryGetValue(id, out var newObj) ? newObj : null));
```

So first create two dictionaries to lookup the old and new objects via Id efficiently. Then collect all Id's and use `Select` to get the old/new object with each Id. If it's not available in the dictionary it will assign `null` to the tuple item.